# Lottery Linearity of Expectation Probability

Tags: probability

Would like to confirm the question below

---

The Lottery Corp (LC) offers the following 
lottery game:

- LC chooses a winning number $w$ in $S=\{0,1,2,\ldots,999\}$.
- If Jack wants to play, he pays $\$1$ and chooses a number $x$ in 
    $S$.

  - If $x=w$, then Jack receives $\$700$ from OLG. In this case, Jack wins $\$699$.
  - Otherwise, $x \neq w$ and Jack does not receive anything. In this case, Jack loses $\$1$.

Assume the following:

- Jack plays this game once per day for one year (i.e., for $365$ 
    days),
- each day, LC chooses a new winning number,
- each day, Jack chooses $x$ uniformly at random from the set $S$, 
    independently from previous choices.

Define the random variable $X$ to be the total amount of dollars that Jack wins during one year. Determine the expected value $E(X)$.

---

My try, I feel like there's something wrong with my way to calculate Jack's winning EACH year. Am I structuring my proof correctly?

$x =$ # of dollars Jack wins in a year

$y =$ Jack's chance to win on any given day, $\frac{1}{1000}$

$z=$ Jack's winning day is on this given day, $\frac{1}{365}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(x) &=& E(y) + E(z)\\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^{1000} k\cdot Pr(y=k) + \sum_{l=1}^{365} l\cdot Pr(z=l)\\
&=& 183 + 500.5\\
&=& 683.5
\end{eqnarray*} 
Since he expected to get a win after 684 ticket buys, and may not win in the first, or second year. However, after 684 days, he will win the lottery and make 700-684 = \$16 dollars.

$\therefore$ Jack will win 16 dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack's expected win on a given day $i$ is $$E[X_i]=699\cdot\frac{1}{1000}-1\cdot\frac{999}{1000}=-0.3$$ Thus his expected win in 365 days is $$E[X]=365*(-0.3)=-109.5$$ That is, Jack's expects to lose 109.5 over the year. That is **intuitively** coherent with the fact that the game is unfair, because the amount one wins is just 700 when there is a chance of $1/1000$ to find it. The game would be fair, if the price was about 1000 dollars or more.

---

Alternatively, the number of days $N$ that Jack wins in a year is binomial random variable with parameters $n=365$ and $p=\frac{1}{1000}$, thus $$E[N]=np=365\cdot\frac{1}{1000}=0.365$$ So he expects to win 0.365 times and lose $365-0.365=364.635$ times. So his expected win is $$E[X]=0.365*699-364.365*1=109.5$$

---

The problem in your approach is the definition of $z$. By defining $z$ like this you implicitly assume that Jack will for sure win some day. That is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Am I too silly for this? On any given day, Jack has a probability to win 699 with probability 1/1000 and to win −1 with probability 999/1000. So, his expected win each day is of course negative: (699−999)/1000=−0.3- the company wins (as always). Playing over a year will result in an expected loss of −0.3∗365.